# What's the purpose of a leading pipe when declaring a type on Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, prettier

Using Prettier I noticed that this code block is formatted to contain an extra leading pipe, see the following example:

```
// before Prettier
let foo: {
    [k: string]: any
} | boolean;

// after Prettier
const actions:
  | {
      [k: string]: any;
    }
  | boolean = true;
```

Notice the pipe added by Prettier on the type declaration.

This could also be declared in a single line, and prettier keeps the format without adding the extra pipe:

```
const actions: { [k: string]: any } | boolean = true;
```

My doubt is why is this pipe added? Does it change anything at the Typescript level?

Comment: It may be to allow for easier addition and deletion of alternations. Also, seeing each `|` on its own indented line followed by the type makes the logic a bit clearer at a glance

Comment: Its just nicer syntax. Very popular in functional languages. Its neutral if there is a `|` as first or not,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's purely stylistic, there is no functional difference.

Consider the following:

```
type Foo = Bar
  | Baz
  | Bap
```

compared to this:

```
type Foo =
  | Bar
  | Baz
  | Bap
```

The second example is cleaner, and it's immediately clear that the three things on the right side of the `|`s are the constituents of the union.

Clearly, you wouldn't add a leading `|` when defining everything on one line:

```
type T = A | B
```