# How to manage multi-options for interface field?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I have an interface:

```
export interface StyledTableProps {
    $gridTemplateColumns:
        | Array<{
                min: string;
                max: string;
          }>
        | {
                min?: string;
                max?: string;
                repeat: number;
          }
        | {
                size: string;
                repeat: number;
          };
}
```

I would like to handle all possible options for the field "$gridTemplateColumns":

```
if (Array.isArray($gridTemplateColumns)) {
    // some code, ts goes ok.
} else if ($gridTemplateColumns.size) {
    > TS2339: Property size does not exist on type
    // some code to handle case
}
```

How could I fix this problem with TS2339?

There is three variants for field:

1. array of objects "min" and "max" fields;
2. object of fields where only field "repeat" - mandatory. Other can be default (by part of realization);
3. object of fields where "size" and "repeat" fields are mandatory. No other fields accepted in this case.

How to implement interface "StyledTableProps" and type checking to fix TS2339 issues and get it fully reliably and typo-safe?

I tried to google, checking field of undefined.

I expect to see no errors from ts and check all arguments if they're wrong according to interface.

Comment: this `$gridTemplateColumns:
        | Array<{` looks like a syntax error. Why the pipe in front?

Comment: @d.k This is valid [TypeScript syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59302392/whats-the-purpose-of-a-leading-pipe-when-declaring-a-type-on-typescript).

Comment: When you are checking `$gridTemplateColumns.size`, `$gridTemplateColumns` may still satisfy the second variant (without the `size` property). You probably want to use type guards in this case. You can find the documentation here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the `$gridTemplateColumns` Union is by using the [in operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing).

> JavaScript has an operator for determining if an object or its prototype chain has a property with a name: the in operator. TypeScript takes this into account as a way to narrow down potential types.

```
export interface StyledTableProps {
  $gridTemplateColumns:
    | Array<{
        min: string;
        max: string;
      }>
    | {
        min?: string;
        max?: string;
        repeat: number;
      }
    | {
        size: string;
        repeat: number;
      };
}

declare const props: StyledTableProps;

if (Array.isArray(props.$gridTemplateColumns)) {
    
} else if ("size" in props.$gridTemplateColumns) {
    
} else {
    
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRgE8AbYAEwBVMAjMgBSgjAGc4BvAKDjgBIBzKAirAAtmBKZUAYQgkArqKQsAXNx5wAPnACCUKJiIAeLhrNxRyFXBYwhSfgG515i5hDXb9py40BfAD5fbVNXC2QAfk87ZB8wtxAomxiHZ3ioYDBgKWskRRo0NPM-YI5fMxYEAC9gaO8i1wysnLg80QKoBv9nEs5yYGxJDLhsCGV4MCZWa0JSCmo6YEZmFmdOBHQ4AAo9AyIAOgQWXcMtyZX9gSERcUkZOUVlAEonsrNz1kvBYUoxCSlgLIFEpVr4APRgswAPQinD8cGAJBYeA22wARJUamjEEg4B8WF9rr9bgCgY8WK9Qjx8YSfn87oCHiCuhDobD4YjkW8NDSrnSSfdgcoWZCNDC4UA)